# MySql DB remote connection is slow

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I am using Magento ver1.5.1. I have the DB in a live serve and Magento files are in local machine.

When I try to access the magento. It takes 30 -35 seconds to load.

Kindly let me know how can we reduce the loading time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://bobbyallen.wordpress.com/2007/11/02/slow-connections-on-remote-mysql-servers/

Comment: I'm using a DB from a docker container and I feel like adding `skip-name-resolve` made things slightly faster but not all too much. There must be a bottleneck still somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Run the code closer to the database and with as fast of connection between the two as you can. Short of that, you can use caching but its very hard to develop with caching enabled because your changes might not be reflected in pages you view.